# Can a function be stored as value in Python dictionary and dictionary saved as pickle? then loaded again?

Tags: python

As above. I'm doing that but I'm getting an error, not sure if because the aforementioend is not pissible.

> EOFError: Ran out of input

The error comes up when I do `np.load(address, allow_pickle=True)`

Comment: In order to tell you what's wrong with your attempt to do this, we need to see your attempt to do this. That is, all of the relevant code, not just the line where the error occurs.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel are you saying that it is possible?

Comment: I am saying that *in order to tell you what's wrong with your attempt to do this, we need to see your attempt to do this. That is, all of the relevant code, not just the line where the error occurs*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sorry for not complying with the rules, I thought my question is generic and is not relavent to a particular code. Anyway, I think it the answer is no, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes function can be stored in dictionary...

```
import pickle

#created three dummy function
def func_add(x,y):
    return x+y

def func_sub(x,y):
    return x-y

def func_prod(x, y):
    return x*y

#storing all three function in a dict
dict_ = {}
dict_['add'] = func_add
dict_['sub'] = func_sub
dict_['prod'] = func_prod

#now saving it it in pickle format
with open('dict_1.pickle', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(dict_, file)

#calling the saved pickle object 
with open('dict_1.pickle', 'rb') as file:
   b = pickle.load(file) 

b['add'](5,3)
#op
8

b['sub'](5,3)
#op 
2

b['prod'](5,3)
#op
15
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try define the function as a string, and execute it by `exec()`
**make_function.py:**

```
import pickle

str_function = '''
def function(str_param, num_param):     # define the function
    print(str_param, num_param)
function(%(str_param)s, %(num_param)d)  # execute it
'''

d = {'str_function': str_function}

with open('functions.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(d, f)
```

**execute_function.py**

```
import pickle

with open('functions.dat', 'rb') as f:
    d = pickle.load(f)

exec(d['str_function'] % dict(str_param="'hello'", num_param=123))
```

Comment: I thought of that too. It's hacky though. Thanks